# What was it called again? [Geometry Logic?]

Tags: geometry

I'm taking the SAT at the end of this week and I wanted to review some simple Geometry laws.  Problem is, I can't seem to find what I remember learning last year in class.  I'm trying to remember about things such as how we know that opposite interior angles are congruent (and things similar).

Does anybody know what these concepts are called so that I might Google them easier **OR** a website that they know of that will explain all these things to me?

**-THANKS!!**

Comment: Try: http://www.khanacademy.org/#geometry

Comment: @JavaMan, Thanks, that looks really cool and helpful! +1 for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you appear to be looking for are the postulates and propositions of Euclidean geometry, a good reference for which is:
http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/toc.html

Though I should warn you now, you mind find this study time to be wasted, the SAT is very light on this sort of thing. You may find your time better spent reviewing material from any pre-algebra classes you have had, if you have any trouble with that material.

Comment: Thanks so much, "Postulate" was the keyword that I was looking for.  Also, by any chance, do you know of any references that include in detail the individual math topics covered by the SAT?

Answer (score 1):

I bet if you type "simple geometry laws" into a search engine (but without the quotes), you'll get some useful hits. Or try "Euclidean geometry" or "plane geometry" as a search term (with the quotes).

Comment: Thanks so much, luckily, deftfyodor found the word I was looking for (postulate).  Yours was also very helpful!  +1 for you!